# For finding own device's MAC address, is NetworkInterface safe to use?

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address, network-interface

I have seen that finding one's own MAC address (Wifi or BT) by standard methods, like this one -

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

have been deprecated since Android M.

Reason given is security of user's data.

However, using NetworkInterface, we can still get the MAC addresses -

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> all = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(all.hasMoreElements()) {
     NetworkInterface nif = all.nextElement();
     if (nif.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wlan0"))
     {
         byte[] macBytes = nif.getHardwareAddress();
         //do stuff here
     }
}
```

Are there cases where this might fail (current versions as well as upcoming versions of Android)?

Answer (score 0):

In our codebase we use both methods for retrieving the MAC address. There's a comment about some devices not returning the MAC address when Wi-Fi is off so there's also a fallback for a default MAC Address if nif.getHardwareAddress(); returns null.

If it's null we set it to Android 6.0 default MAC Address: "02:00:00:00:00:00"